# Surface area of a cone contained in a cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Given the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$, $z\geq 0$ and the cylinder $z^2+y^2=64$

I am looking for the surface area of the section of the cone inside of the cylinder.

I can parametrize the cone as:

$r(t,\theta)=\langle tcos(\theta), tsin(\theta), t \rangle$

The cone gives me the inequality:

$z^2 \leq 64-y^2 \iff z \leq \sqrt{64-y^2}$ (since $z \geq 0$)

Plugin in the values of the parametrization:

$t^2 \leq 64-t^2\sin^2(\theta) \iff t \leq \frac{8}{\sqrt{sin^2(\theta)+1}}$

I know the Jacobian of the partial derivatives is:

$|r_\theta\times r_t| = \sqrt2t$

Thus the surface area should be:

$\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\sqrt{\frac{8}{sin^2(\theta)+1}}}_0\sqrt2t$ $dt d\theta$

However with this method I end up trying to integrate $\frac{1}{sin^2(\theta)+1}$ with respect to $\theta$ which not only do I not know how to do, but it makes me think my method is wrong.

EDIT: attempting to compute that integral with the help of wolfram tells me the surface area is 0, which is trivially false. So I have done something wrong.

Comment: minor mistake if ypu look at it it has 2 variables

Comment: How is it not? It's a set of circles whose radius increases as the altitude increases, how is this not a parametrization of the surface?

Comment: my appologies I was tired when writing the question, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on solving the problem using parametrization, then try to make sense of the following hint.

**Hint:** A parametrization of your surface can be given by
\begin{align}
\phi(u, v) = (8u\cos v, 4\sqrt{2} u \sin v, u \sqrt{32+32\cos^2 v})
\end{align}
where $0\leq u \leq 1$ and $0\leq v\leq 2\pi$. Remember to check that  $\|\phi_u\times \phi_v\| = 64 u$.

**Additional Hint:** Parametrize the boundary of your generalized cone, then "connect it to the origin" via "scaling".

Comment: @Makogan if you plug in $t=1$ then you will get $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 1)$ which is a circle on the $z=1$ plane. But that's not the boundary of your surface.

Comment: @JackyChong Right, but that's why I was trying to bound $0\leq t \leq 8/(sin^2(\theta)+1)$ Which I thought was gonna give me the correct boundary.

Comment: Then what do you get when you plug in $t = \frac{8}{\sin^2\theta +1}$ which surely should give you the boundary of your surface if your parametrization is correct.

Comment: That was crazy! The hint helped me to parametrize the volume of the solid instead of just the area. Thanks @JackyChong

Answer (score 1):

Note that the intersection of $x,y$ values giving the two surfaces
$$
z^2=x^2+y^2,\;z\geq 0\;\text{and}\;z^2+y^2=64\implies \frac{y^2}{(4\sqrt{2})^2}+\frac{x^2}{8^2}=1
$$
So the projection of the surface bounded by the intersection of the cylinder and the cone is given by 
$$
D=\left\{x,y:\frac{y^2}{(4\sqrt{2})^2}+\frac{x^2}{8^2}\leq 1\right\}
$$
or an ellipse with major axis $8$ and minor axis $4\sqrt{2}$. The normal to the cone is 
$$
\left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},1 \right)
$$
which has norm 
$
\sqrt{2}$, so your surface integral is 
$$
\sqrt{2}\int\int_{D}\mathrm dA=\sqrt{2}\pi(4\sqrt{2})(8)=64\pi
$$

Comment: I am hesitant, you definetely answered the question that I asked and this is indeed the correct result but you avoided using the parametric representation of the surface and the jacobian. So, you gave me the right answer, but I the point of the question is to solve the problem using the parametric representaion :P.

Comment: ok, then name $x=t$ and $y=s$ in the above

Comment: it is particularly easy to parametrize surfaces given by the graph of a function, which yours is. You should not pretend it is not and make your life more difficult

Comment: It's not to make my life difficult, this is a calculus III question, and although off course this method works, the point of the question as it was asked is to learn how to use the method that I was trying to use to compute the surface area. Like you sir are absolutely correct and your math is indeed flawless, I am not saying your method isn't easier, just that It's not in the form I was expecting.